# Unresolved reference during inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, warnings

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class FooObject(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
    
    def do_stuff(self):
        ...doing stuff
    
    
objects = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_obj = FooObject()
objects.add(my_obj)


for obj in objects:
    obj.do_stuff()
```

The code works fine. However, last line Pycharm gives me a warning:

**Unresolved attribute reference 'do_stuff' for class 'Sprite'**

Very understandable, normally i would just put a placeholder method in the super-class that gets overwritten by the inheriting class. However, the Sprite class isnt mine and i dont want to mess with it, so what is the recommended course of action here? Ignore the warning?

Comment: Add a type hint to declare `objects` to be a `Sequence[FooObject]`…?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but when more classes are added, this will get messy with always having to add them to the Union in the Sequence. Also, while pycharm would probably be quiete, i didnt really change the actual code, so i m not sure if i m following best practice there and run into problems later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for existence of the method before calling:

```py
for obj in objects:
    if hasattr(obj, 'do_stuff'):
        obj.do_stuff()
```

or

```py
for obj in objects:
    if isinstance(obj, FooObject):
        obj.do_stuff()
```

where `FooObject` could be the child class of all children having a `do_stuff` member.

Edit:
From the comments it could be usefull to create an intermediate abstract class, named `ActiveStripe` for grouping all descendants having a `do_stuff` member.

Comment: i was thinking of doing this, however
1. i may have more classes later on that are in objects and share the do_stuff instance, so i would always have to add them here.
2. this would silently ignore if there is an object without the .do_stuff in objects, however if this was to happen, i would like it to throw an error actually (i guess i could throw one manually, but it seems over-engineered)

Comment: If I were you, I would group all the classes having `do_stuff` member into an "ActiveSprite" parent class. This should help keeping things tractable.

Comment: Probably that is the way to go. I kinda wanted to prevent having a super long inhertence line, as such code is horrible to read (and some classes already inheritate from things like "MovingObject" etc). Still i think adding another layer of inheritence may be the best way to go, just wanted to make sure i m not overlooking something obvious. Edit that into your answer and i ll accept it as answer. Thanks for your time :)